# log4j2 - Changing the Output file during execution

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

I'm switching over from log4j to log4j2 and converted everything smoothly except the following situation.  In my code, I have a test engine that outputs text to a file.  I'm using log4j2 to handle the logging.  I want to create a separate log file for each test, with the name of the file being the test name.

For example, test1 would output to test1.log and test2 would output to test2.log.  This was possible in log4j by using this code...

```
private Category testOutput = Category.getInstance("ModelTestOutput");
FileAppender outFile = new FileAppender(new PatternLayout("%m%n"), fileName, false);
testOutput.addAppender(outFile);
```

However, I can't seem to find the new log4j2 pattern to match this.

I have it currently set up like this...

```
protected Logger testOutput = LogManager.getLogger(); 
//unknown function to tailor the output file name
//something similar to above, like testOutput.addAppender()
```

and in the log4j2.xml file

```
    <property name="test-file">test.log</property>
    <appender type="File" name="TestLog" fileName="${test-path}${test-file}">
        <layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="%m%n"></layout>
    </appender>
    <logger name="tester.fvt" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="TestLog" />
    </logger>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to change the target log file name dynamically using a RoutingAppender and the ThreadContext map. The FAQ page has a good example: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files